# Need to alter this code to extract all data from table instead of just one row

Tags: vba, loops, excel

Hey everyone I found this awesome code that helped me get the loop I needed but I am trying to alter this to extract all the data from the word tables not just one row of the tables.. Any help would be great. I know it going to be a simple fix just haven't been able to get any to work on my own. Thanks

```
Sub wordScrape()

    Dim wrdDoc As Object, objFiles As Object, fso As Object, wordApp As Object
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer

    FolderName = "C:\code" ' Change this to the folder containing your word documents

    Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.application")
    Set objFiles = fso.GetFolder(FolderName).Files

    x = 1
    For Each wd In objFiles
    If InStr(wd, ".docx") And InStr(wd, "~") = 0 Then
        Set wrdDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(wd.Path, ReadOnly = True)
        sh1.Cells(x, 1) = wd.Name
        sh1.Cells(x, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(wrdDoc.Tables(3).Cell(Row:=3,       Column:=2).Range)
        'sh1.Cells(x, 3) = ....more extracted data....
        x = x + 1
    wrdDoc.Close
    End If

Next wd
wordApp.Quit
End Sub`
```

Comment: Probably need to revamp the line `sh1.Cells(x, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(wrdDoc.Tables(3).Cell(Row:=3,       Column:=2).Range)` to use a loop that goes through each desired table and then each row to extract your data.  It actually probably won't be as "simple" of a fix as you said it would, but that depends on what you consider simple I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub wordScrape()


Dim wd As New Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim tbl As Word.Table
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim s As String
Dim r As Range
FolderName = "C:\code" ' Change this to the folder containing your word documents

Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set r = sh1.Range("a1")
s = Dir(FolderName & "\*.doc*")
Do While s <> ""
    If InStr(wd, "~") = 0 Then
        Set wdDoc = wd.Documents.Open(FolderName & "\" & s, False, True, False)
            For Each tbl In wdDoc.Tables

                For x = 1 To t.Rows.Count
                    r = wdDoc.Name
                    For y = 1 To t.Columns.Count

                        r.Offset(0, y) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(t.Cell(Row:=x, Column:=y).Range)
                    Next y
                    Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
                Next x
            Next tbl
        wdDoc.Close False
    End If
    s = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

Now, this is off the top of my head, it assumes a reference to word is set (tools,references in the VBE) and it crucially assumes that every table has no merged cells - if they do it will break. But it gets you started

Comment: Thanks!! this is great but I get an error on the "For x = 1 To t.Rows.Count" line....